# How to get the value of a player statistic?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am developing a Minecraft Fabric mod with custom player stats.
Here is how I created a custom player stat:

```java
public class ModStats {
    public static final Identifier MINING_STAT = new Identifier(ExampleMod.MOD_ID, "mining_stat");

    public static void registerModStats() {
        Registry.register(Registries.CUSTOM_STAT, "mining_stat", MINING_STAT);
        Stats.CUSTOM.getOrCreateStat(MINING_STAT, StatFormatter.DEFAULT);
    }

}
```

`registerModStats()` is called in the Mod main class.
I increase the stat using a `MiningToolItemMixin`:

```java
@Mixin(MiningToolItem.class)
public class MiningToolItemMixin {
    @Inject(at = @At("TAIL"), method = "postMine")
    private void postMine(ItemStack stack, World world, BlockState state, BlockPos pos, LivingEntity miner,
            CallbackInfoReturnable<Boolean> info) {
        if (miner instanceof PlayerEntity player) {
            player.incrementStat(ModStats.MINING_STAT);
        }
        System.out.println("MiningToolItemMixin");
    }
}
```

Everything works finde but **how can I get the stat value in other parts of the code?**

I tired to get the stat via the `PlayerEntitiy` object but there are only methods to increase stats and to retreive stats.